# Getting timeout on vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Today I have started learning Vagrant. Creating first, base virtual machine ( hashicorp/precise32) went pretty smooth. So I wanted to test another box, this time :puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-32-puppet. However im getting this msg : `default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...` I have read that it might be because of disabled virtualization, but as I understand virtualization it's only needed for 64bit machines. So what can be problem here? Could anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try

- increase 'ssh_wait_timeout'
- increase 'boot_wait'
- activate the vb.gui options in Vagrantfile
- increase the 'config.vm.boot_timeout options in Vagrantfile
- disable the shared folder with this line `config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true` in vagrantfile
- update Vagrant (latest is 1.8.1)
- update VirtualBox (latest is 5.0.12)
- cross the finger

Comment: So i have the latest versions of both vagrant and virtualbox. Tried all of those suggestions but unfortunatelly none solved my problem :( Only turningu on virtualization seems to work however I have no idea why, because i only want to use 32bit system. Any other thoughts ?  Or idea why virtualization helps and why one box works while other does not?